# Is it fine to not await for a log.write() promise inside a cloud run container?

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-logging

I'm using `@google-cloud/logging` to log some stuff out of my `express` app over on Cloud Run.

Something like this:

**routeHandler.ts**

```
import { Logging } from "@google-cloud/logging";

const logging = new Logging({ projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID });
const logName = LOG_NAME; 
const log = logging.log(logName);

const resource = {
  type: "cloud_run_revision",
  labels: { ... }
};

export const routeHandler: RequestHandler = (req,res,next) => {
  try {
    // EXAMPLE: LOG A WARNING
    const metadata = { resource, severity: "WARNING" };
    const entry = log.entry(metadata,"SOME WARNING MSG");
    await log.write(entry);
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  catch(err) {
    // EXAMPLE: LOG AN ERROR
    const metadata = { resource, severity: "ERROR" };
    const entry = log.entry(metadata,"SOME ERROR MSG");
    await log.write(entry);
    return res.sendStatus(500);
  }
};
```

You can see that the `log.write(entry)` is asynchronous. So, ***in theory***, it would be recommended to await for it. But here is what the documentation from `@google-cloud/logging` says:

[image]

[Doc link](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/logging/latest/)

And I got no problem with that. In my real case, even if the `log.write()` fails, it is inside a `try-catch` and any errors will be handled just fine.

My problem is that it kind of conflicts with the Cloud Run documentation:

[image]

[Doc link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#avoiding_background_activities)

**Note:** If I don't wait for the `log.write()` call, I'll end the request cycle by responding to the request

And Cloud Run does behave like that. A couple weeks back, I tried to respond immediately to the request and fire some long background job. And the process kind of halted for a while, and I think it restarted once it got another request. Completely unpredictable. And when I ran this test I'm mentioning here, I even had a `MIN_INSTANCE=1` set on my cloud run service container. Even that didn't allow my background job to run smoothly. Therefore, I don't think it's fine to leave the process doing background stuff when I've finished handling a request (by doing the *"fire and forget"* approach).

So, what should I do here?

Comment: Even an instance which is "severely limited" will probably be able to log stuff just fine. What they want you to avoid is starting long running background tasks to do such as recurring tasks or something.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren thanks. But they even mention that the CPU might get disabled. What are the risks here?

Comment: I have very little experience in this area but I would assume that that the CPU will be throttled first so that the instance can be brought back up quickly but then completely disabled (ie shut down) after a longer period of inactivity. So firing of some small logging calls that in most cases will finish within milliseconds shouldn't be a problem. If for some reason the CPU is completely disabled with pending log calls your log messages will probably be dropped.

Comment: @cbdeveloper are you using the fire and forget approach? I am interested in knowing if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki based on @Karl-JorhanSjögren's correct assumption in the comments.

For Log calls on apps running in Cloud Run you are indeed encouraged to take a Fire and Forget approach, since you don't really need to force synchronicity on that.

As mentioned in the comments replying to your concern on the CPU being disabled after the request is fulfilled, the CPU will be throttled first so that the instance can be brought back up quickly and completely disabled after a longer period of inactivity. So firing of small logging calls that in most cases will finish within milliseconds shouldn't be a problem.

What is mentioned in the documentation is targeted at processes that run for Longer periods of time.